# What does "putting someone on" mean?

Tags: meaning

Like in this example:

> He was worried that X was **putting him on**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case it means to tease someone, meaning 2 below (from [Answers.com](http://www.answers.com/topic/put-on#ixzz1DgiBofBK)).

> **put-on** n. Slang
>
> 1. A deceptive outward appearance.
> 2. The act of teasing or misleading someone, especially for amusement.
> 3. Something, such as a prank, intended as a hoax or joke; a spoof.

Note that this link is for the noun form, but the verb ("to put someone on") has the same meaning.

Sample usage:

> Bill said he was going to help me fix my car, but it turns out he was just putting me on.

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, related sayings might include:

> Are you **having me on**? (*To kid or mislead someone* )
>
> Are you **taking the mickey** out of me? (*Teasing or making fun of someone*)
>
> He's **pulled a fast one**. (*To trick or mislead someone*)

Answer (score 1):

He was worried that X was playing a trick on him, or setting him up for a little prank; in American English usage it's generally used to indicate that X is trying to get him to believe something extremely improbable (and not actually true), and at the point where he finally accepts the truth of the improbable thing, X could say "No, I was just putting you on."

Answer (score 1):

The NOAD describes *put someone on* as informal for *deceive*, *hoax*.

Answer (score 0):

Put on here means "**pretending**" or "**play-acting**".

Comment: The usual infinitive form of the latter is "play-acting".

Answer (score 0):

The English English equivalent being "taking the piss" -is that fair?